# How to notify @all using curl hipchat api?

Tags: json, curl, hipchat

I am able to post to Hipchat using curl.  But I can seem to have it take the @all It prints it as part of the message but it doesn't notify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `notify` property to `true` - This is set to `false` by default.

Comment: @RobertoTheLaker are you able to mark this as answered please?